# Error with DataGrid, C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to map a list of classes to a datagrid and I am getting a very strange error. I have a linked list called "AllVars" made up of the following class:

```
 public class LoggedVariable
        {
            public LoggedVariable()
            {
                Values = new List<float>();
            }
            public List<float> Values { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public bool drawn { get; set; }
        }
```

And there are 8 of these classes, with the values list populated in each, and I am trying to display these values on a datagrid by first mapping them to a DataTable then binding the table to the grid.

```
        Why = new DataSet();
        GraphData = new DataTable();


        foreach(LoggedVariable element in AllVars)
        {
            GraphData.Columns.Add(element.name);
        }

        for (int t = 0; t < AllVars[0].Values.Count; t++)
        {
            foo = GraphData.NewRow();
            foreach (LoggedVariable element in AllVars)
            {
                foo[element.name] = element.Values[t];
            }
            GraphData.Rows.Add(foo);
        }
        Why.Tables.Add(GraphData);
        LoggedGrid.ItemsSource = Why.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

However when I do this, the third, fifth and 7th columns show no data, while the table before mapping it shows that there is data in those columns before mapping it to the data grid...any ideas?

Comment: How would that look like? you want to have a column for every `LoggedVariable` and a row  for every list of values ?

Comment: A column for every variable, and a row for each value that variable takes throughout the log sequence

Answer (score 0):

So...The various columns were not being recognized because they had periods at the end of thei r names...E.g

"Test Values for temp." <--- These values would not display

"Test Values for temp"  <--- These would

Very strange